I'm building an app based on the Photorealistic 3D Tiles API, but the relevant copyright attributes aren't shown in any JSON responses from the API
I'm building a custom Python client for an app that uses the 3D Tiles API. As it states in the documentation in the documentation, I need to display the copyright attributes on screen that are associated with the tiles that are being used. However it seems that I don't get any asset attribute/key from any of the responess, either a root JSON when a new external tileset is requested, or at a leaf node of a high LOD tile.
I don't get any asset attributes that show copyright info when either requesting a root tileset:
requests.get(f"{URL}{URI}?key={API_KEY}")

Or a further tileset:
requests.get(f"{URL}{URI}?{session}&key={API_KEY}")

Instead, the structure of the returned JSONS are:
{'asset': {'version': '1.0'},
 'geometricError': 1e+100,
 'root': {'boundingVolume': {'box': [0,
    0,
    0,
    ...}},
 'extensionsUsed': ['3DTILES_content_gltf'],
 'extensionsRequired': ['3DTILES_content_gltf']}

Rather than what is in the documentation:
{
  "asset": {
    "version": "2.0",
    "generator": "draco_decoder",
    "copyright": "Data SIO, NOAA, U.S. Navy, NGA, GEBCO;Landsat / Copernicus"
  }
}

Where can I find the correct copyright attributes?
Many thanks.

I wouldn't bother. Do what the docs say you have to do. Display the copyright info. If it's not there, it's not there. Not your problem. You've followed the docs.
